# Jquery, how to append texts to iframe instead of replacing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I use javascript to replace texts instead of append it. Now I would like to use Jquery instead of Javascript and append it instead of replacing text. How I do that? **document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc = transcript;** is where it put text and replace in iframe.

Here my javascript code,

```
var text = "", transcript = "", cap = "", text2 = "", cap2 = "", cap3 = "", cap4 = "";

for(var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length; i++)
{
    var cueLineStart1 = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
    var cueLineStart2 = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i+1][0]);
    var cueLineStart3 = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i+2][0]);
    var cueLineStart4 = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i+3][0]);
    var cueEnd4 = cueLineStart4 + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i+3][1]);

    cap = subtitleArray[i][2];
    cap2 = subtitleArray[i+1][2];
    cap3 = subtitleArray[i+2][2];
    cap4 = subtitleArray[i+3][2];
    i+=3;

    if (video.currentTime >= cueLineStart1 && video.currentTime <= cueEnd4)
    {
          transcript = cap + " " + cap2 + " " + cap3 + " " + cap4;
    }

    $("#subtitle").html(text);

    document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc = transcript;
}
```

HTML5 iframe code,

```
<div  class="frame">
            <iframe id ="frame" srcdoc="<p></p>" width="930"></iframe>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try looking through the jQuery documentation. They probably have your answer: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: why would you want to use jQuery instead of JavaScript if JavaScript works just fine?

Comment: Because I want to learn how to use jQuery.

Comment: well, can't argue with that ;-) see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reloading the iframe, you can access its content, just like you would do for any regular Web page.

Here is a JavaScript cross-browser example:

```
var ifr=document.getElementById("frame");
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
```

With jQuery:

```
var doc=$("iframe").contents();
```

There's an example in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).